# Is there a possibility to simply display the next element on a layer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have to check all the elements on a layer and I'm looking for an easy way to go through all of them. One option would be to open the attribute table and just always click on the next line and then "move to selection". I would prefer an option where I just click on an arrow or use a shortcut and QGIS just jumps to the next element, so that I don't have to be aware of not missing a line and just needing half the amount of clicks. Is there anything like that in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

I just found the selectnext Plugin http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/selenext that does exactly what I want.

EDIT: Selenext seems to be missing in the repository lately. It can be installed by downloading it from https://github.com/geodrinx/selenext unzipping the file and copying the folder to ~/.qgis2/python/plugins (Linux only). After a restart of QGIS it will be available.

Comment: To work properly, the layer and the project need to be in the same CRS.

Comment: Have you found a method to do this in QGIS 3.x? The current implementation of selenext on github is using Qt4 and I can't therefore install the plugin in QGIS 3. I think it's strange not being able to iterate through features of the active layer is not a more common issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for the current version. No need for it right now. I wish you good luck and it would be great if you could update/add the answer once you found a solution.