# Quickly browsing of features for the active vector layer?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, features

I often need to view on the canvas the (selected or not) features from the current active vector layer.

In this situation, I only need to view something on the canvas, without doing anything on the canvas itself (so, the active window is always the Attribute Table).

This is what I usually do:

1. Open the Attribute Table for the current active layer;
2. Select the first feature;
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> button (i.e. the "Pan map to the selected row" button);
4. Minimize the Attribute Table;
5. View something on the canvas for the current feature;
6. Go to the first step until needed.

Is there a way (a method, a shortcut) for directly ***browsing*** every feature on the canvas without the needing of going backwards and forwards with the Attribute Table? I mean, something like a *"next"* button?

(I may use the workaround of splitting the windows of the Attribute Table and of the canvas within the monitor, or also docking the Atrribute Table, but I would like to work on the full QGIS window).

---

**EDIT** I saw that my question was casted as a duplicate of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180499/is-there-a-possibility-to-simply-display-the-next-element-on-a-layer) question. The two questions are very similiar, but I think it should be left as open for two reasons:

1. the related duplicated question doesn't have an accepted answer;
2. my question is slightly different because I'm looking for the possibility of displaying only the selected features (and the @Joseph's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/228207/87487), that I marked as accepted, answers well to my request).

Comment: You can have a look at the plugin "Item Browser". Its description seems to match your requirements. http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/itembrowser/

Comment: Many thanks, @GermánCarrillo! I tried the plugin and it's really simple to use!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is to download the **selenext** plugin from the menubar:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
```

Once download, modify the *selenext.py* file by replacing the following in both the `run()` and `runPrevious()` functions:

```
box = vlayer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
self.iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(box)
self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

with:

```
self.iface.actionPanToSelected().trigger()
```

Reload the plugin. Now whenever you click on the the next or previous icons, the canvas will pan to the selected feature:

[image: selenext icons]

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but can you find the plugin from the repository?

Comment: @mgri - Yes, it's not marked as experimental or depreciated...weird! Otherwise you can download it as a .zip file from the [GitHub](https://github.com/geodrinx/selenext) page, then extract it to your plugins folder. Note that you may need to change the folder name from `selenext-master` to just `selenext` =)

Comment: @mgri - Most welcome! Hope it was helpful :)

Answer (score 11):

This functionality is now integrated in QGIS 3.10 (not sure about previous versions):

1. Open the attribute table of the vector layer in question.
2. Click on the ***Switch to form view*** icon on the bottom right of the attribute table.
3. On the bottom left, just below the list of features, choose to either

   - ***Automatically pan to the current feature*** or
   - ***Automatically zoom to the current feature***.
4. (Optionally activate the ***Highlight current feature on map*** option.)
5. You can then either click on the feature of interest or click on the left/right arrow to browse through the features.

Alternatively you can now also setup a **keyboard shortcut** (go to *Settings* > *Keyboard Shortcuts...*) to ***Edit previous/next feature in attribute table*** (respectively `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`[` and `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`]` by default on my system).

You may also want to use the **Dock Attribute Table** option for convenience.

[image]